# adding or substract a field value using another field in mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get carry forward a field value using another field

This is my table transaction

```
------------------------------
id   | amount  | is_income    |
------------------------------
1    | 400     |1
2    | 100     |0
3    | 300     |1
```

I want to get the result like

```
--------------------------------------
id   | amount  | is_income |Balance  |
--------------------------------------
1    | 400     |1          | 400
2    | 100     |0          | 300
3    | 300     |1          | 600
```

If  is_income field is 1 then add amount with previous amount. and if is_income field is 0 then subtract with previous amount.

if any method to get result without stored procedure ?

Comment: Can you create a sql fiddle?

Comment: if is_income is 1 then adding previous amount means? In your example,id = 3 row is having 1 so adding with previous amount should be 400 not 600 as per your Balance shown

Comment: @M3ghana it seems he wants to add with the balance - 300 + 300 (previous balance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @balance = 0;
SELECT * , IF( is_income =1, @balance := @balance + amount, @balance := @balance - amount ) AS balance FROM  `your table name `
```

Comment: Thanks for your result.